# Motor driver not working properly in case we connect motor to it

Tags: arduino-uno

We are making a Bluetooth controlled RC car. when we connect our motor (moderate power) to motor driver then  Bluetooth module is automatically disconnected after taking initial command from Arduino code ,and if we connect our led (low power) instead of Motors to motor driver then project is working fine. what could be the possible problem?

Comment: Tell us which motor it is and which battery you use. The motor might ask ten times more current than the battery can deliver.

Comment: I am using a 4volts rechargeable battery with a supply of 2Ampere hour.and motors are of moderate power and taking current of 7 amperes each when connected independently to battery.

Comment: And motor driver is L298n type.

Comment: Can you give the brand and type of the battery and the motor and a link to them? Please add the extra information to your question. The l298n can be used with a 12v battery and a small motor, but not with a 4v battery. Do you know the stall current of the motor?

Comment: Ok let me try a 12volts battery to my setup.

Comment: Are those 12v motors?

Comment: @Jot, that appears to be a secret .... lol

Comment: These motors can also be run by 4volts supply. As you suggested to give motor driver 12volts supply,it worked fine. And thanks for your precious suggestions.

Comment: @jot ,if you want to help me more ,please post a circuit diagram showing different connections to arduino uno,motor driver l298n, and hc05 bluetooth module to the motors. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I used an external battery to supply the motor, and a BJT as a switch to trigger it (Base connected to Arduino).